# Why doesnt QWebView display any images when loaded via setHtml?

Tags: c++, image, qt

Whenever I try to load a page via:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
view->setUrl(QUrl(QString("https://registration.experient-inc.com/HTMLProduction/ShowCES131/ConfirmationImages/CES131_Header.JPG"))); // this does not load images
//view->setUrl(QUrl(QString("http://www.google.com"))); // <= this does load images
```

Why does loading via a string not load the related images? How do I get it to do so? (The related images are on the web and are specified using absolute URLs)

Thanks!

UPDATE: this appears to related to the fact that the url for the image is `https`. When I manually changed it to http, it loaded the image. This is not a fix however, as sometimes the website will require https. Furthermore, i get a connection timed out when I check the error. This is odd because it can access the non-https version of the site and so can any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! This is an OpenSSL issue! `curl -v "https://registration.experient-inc.com/HTMLProduction/ShowCES131/ConfirmationImages/CES131_Header.JPG"` does not work either!